# I want to add the date in MM/DD/YYY after getting the date in YYY-MM-DD

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber

Below are the steps that i have done:
I have read the table and have taken the date in the last row - the date being in YYY-MM-DD
The date gets incremented by 10 and shows the result in YYY-MM-DD format.
But my problem is i need to enter the Date in MM/DD/YYYY format and iam not sure how to do that
Below is my code:
List lastdate = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//table[contains(@class,'mat-table')]//tr/td[5])[last()]"));
int rowcount = lastdate.size();
System.out.println("Get the rowcount:"+rowcount);

```
            for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++)
            {
                String datetext = lastdate.get(i).getText();
             //Specifying date format that matches the given date
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
             
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            
            try{
                
               //Setting the date to the given date
                
                c.setTime(sdf.parse(datetext));- datetext - will take the date from the last row of the table which is 2000-04-15.
                
             
               
            }catch(ParseException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
               
            //Number of Days to add
            int daysToIncrement = 10;
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, daysToIncrement);  
            //Date after adding the days to the given date
            
            String newDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            System.out.println("Get the New Date:"+newDate);
```

}

When i print the result - it shows the date as 2000-04-25

**But i need to add the date in the create screen in MM/DD/YYYY.
Any leads on how to do this ... i.e convert the new date to  MM/DD/YYYY ....**

Comment: Instead of using `sdf` to format the date again at the end, create a new `SimpleDateFormat` with the required format string `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdfs = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY");
    String newDate = sdfs.format(c.getTime());
    you mean need to do like this ? can you please confirm

Comment: See the answer by Alex below. Note: Upper/lowercase letters are important in the format string. You need to use `MM/dd/yyyy`, not `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++)
{
    String datetext = lastdate.get(i).getText();
    //Specifying date format that matches the given date
    SimpleDateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        //Setting the date to the given date
        c.setTime(inputDateFormat.parse(datetext));- datetext - will take the date from the last row of the table which is 2000-04-15.
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   
    //Number of Days to add
    int daysToIncrement = 10;
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, daysToIncrement);  
    //Date after adding the days to the given date

    String newDate = outputDateFormat.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println("Get the New Date:"+newDate);
```